# Raffle - Odds of winning as one person/multiple tickets vs multiple persons/one ticket

Tags: probability, expected-value

Each week there is a lottery. X tickets are sold. There are Y people buying those tickets. There are N winners in one week. Buyers of the tickets are identified. If you buy Y tickets as a same person, you can still win only once, but the odds of you winning are Y times bigger.
If one identified buyer buys 1 ticket he has $\frac{1}{X}$ odds of winning P dollars where P is the prize money.
If one identified buyer buys 2 tickets he will have $\frac{2}{X}$ odds of winning, an the prize money is the same.
If I can somehow fake my id and buy 2 tickets as 2 separate persons the odds of winning P dollars with one draw is still $\frac{2}{X}$ and also I have a change of winning more money. Odds of that happening shoul be $\frac{1}{X}$+$\frac{1}{X-1}$.
If I'd somehow fake my id J times then odds of me winning the lottery once would be J times bigger, plus I'd now have a change to win up to J*P amount of money.

**How to design the lottery so that the buyer wouldn't be incentivised to fake ID's and buy tickets as multiple persons? So that the expected return value (EV) would be same, no matter if he buys J tickets as one person or as J different persons?**

I assume I'd have to give more weight to any person holding multiple tickets. So odds of him winning are more than $\frac{J}{X}$. So that if he'd participate in let's say 10000 weeks in a row, it wouldn't matter if he'd buy tickets each week with the same ID or with different ID's. The EV would be the same after those 10000 weeks.

I've formulated it so that it may look like a homework assignment, but honest to god it's not. I am actually designing such a lottery and I've just experimented with different code snippets on how to make it work, but haven't found any good solution yet.

I'll give an example also to perhaps make it more clear:

There is a lottery and there are 9 ticket holders and 100 tickets. 2 of the holders will be drawn as winners.
One holder has 20 tickets and 8 holders have 10 tickets.
Two of the ten ticket holders are actually the same person falsely acting as two.
How to increase the chance of the honest 20 ticket holder winning so much that the EV would be the same as the 10*2 ticket holder? So that the honest guy would win that much more often across multiple lotteries that it would even out the times when 10x2 ticket holder would win twice the amount of money.

Comment: I don't understand.  If we *know* the buyer is holding multiple tickets, then the original scheme seems to work just fine...limit the number of prizes that person can get to just one.  If we don't know if persons $A,B$ are working together, then any scheme either rewards the joint party or punishes an honest, single ticket holder.

Comment: *"If you buy Y tickets as a same person, you can still win only once, but the odds of you winning are Y times bigger."* << This sentence is apparently false, unless the lottery system is pretty weird. If I buy Y tickets, then the expectation of the number of winning tickets I have will be Y times bigger; but the probability that at least one ticket is winning will be less than Y times bigger. For instance, if there are 10 tickets and 5 of them are winning tickets, then: if I buy 1 ticket, I have probability 1/2 of winning; if I buy 2 tickets, then I only have probability 7/9 of winning.

Comment: In the extreme, if the number of tickets $X$ is extremely large, and a proportion $p$ of the tickets are winning, then if I buy 2 tickets, my probability of having at least one winning ticket will be $2p-p^2$, which is a bit less than $2p$.

Comment: Also, first you say *"Each week there is a lottery. X tickets are sold. There are Y people buying those tickets. There are N winners in one week."* Which appears to imply that more than one tickets are winning tickets. But then you say *"If one identified buyer buys 1 ticket he has 1/X odds of winning"* which appears to imply that there is exactly one winning ticket.

Comment: @Stef My bad. The odds are not 1/X, the odds are about number-of-winning-tickets/X (actually they can fluctuate heavily depending on the distribution of tickets/persons, because if one person wins then all of his tickets are removed for the next draw). If you are the Nth winning ticket, then you can't win again in N+1 draws, even if you hold multiple tickets (unless you impersonate multiple players).

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Tickets don't win. Ticket holders win. Each holder can win only once. If one holder has more than one ticket then odds of him being drawn are higher, but he can still win only once.

Comment: @Stef I added an example also to make my question more clear

Comment: It looks to me like a simple solution is to make sure that the probability of winning is exactly proportional to the number of held tickets. Then the expected gain will be exactly proportional to the number of held tickets, no matter whether all the tickets are held under one name or several fake names. As I pointed out, this is different from usual lotteries, where the probability of winning is less than proportional to the number of held tickets.

Comment: "How to design the lottery... so that the expected return value (EV) would be same, no matter if he buys J tickets as one person or as J different persons?" has different answers that will work depending on which aspects of the lottery you are allowed to change. Those ought to be specified, otherwise, you may get answers that work but I think you will not be happy with - for example, removing the constraint that the gamblers need to provide ID to purchase tickets will obviously work, but I think this is what you don't want right?

Comment: If you use the naive way (i.e. you just assign the first prize proportional to the number of tickets any holder holds, than remove the first prize winner's tickets and assign the second prize with same logic amongst the remaining tickets and players), the EV will be the same whether a player "splits" themselves in two or not. What might change is that, by splitting, a player will have a chance to win multiple prizes (but of course the chance of winning none increases).